# How to resolve NIC service IDs (GUIDs)?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface, guid

Is there a way to resolve NIC service IDs (the GUID assigned to each hardware NIC) from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the actual GUID that the machine has assigned to your nics, use `netsh` from the cmd line (you may need to start the *Wired AutoConfig* and/or *WLAN AutoConfig* services first).

For wired NICs:

```
netsh lan show interfaces
```

And for wireless NICs:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

The output will include the GUIDs of each network interface.

Comment: yes, I mean the GUID, service ID was not my terminology. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to MAC addresses?

If so, the `arp` command is your friend.  `arp -a` will show all the addresses your OS knows about.  `arp -a <IP>` will display just the MAC address of a specific host.  If you don't have a GUID on a specific host, pinging them should pick it up.  That being said, this will only work on hosts on the local network.  Packets sent to/from external networks will utilize the MAC address of the local gateway.


--Christopher Karel